# symfony2 FosUserBundle custom mobile view

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

Hi,

I have a site that provides two versions for browsers and mobiles.

I use the FOSUserBundle which provides views. I'd like to customize these views for the mobile version of my app, how can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FOSUserBundle** has nothing to do with providing two versions for browsers and mobiles.

To do this, you will have to go with **CSS**. This is an [example](http://www.seabreezecomputers.com/tips/mobile-css.htm), probably not the best, but this will give you an indication on how to do this. You can use a [javascript redirection](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/redirect-mobile-devices/), to redirect your mobile users to the appropriate template.